# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies... and requires a model item of type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Got this error when I launch my 'Details' inside my Index on 'Firmas' (Generic auto-generated MS code):

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqQ43.png)

This is my model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using actiTest2.Context;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace actiTest2.Models
{
    public class PcontacFirmasModel
    {
        public Pcontac pcontac { get; set; }
        public Firmas firmas { get; set; }
    }
}
```

An the only call that I try to do atm:

```
@model actiTest2.Models.PcontacFirmasModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = Html.DisplayFor(model => model.firmas.NOMCOMP);
}
```

Comment: You probably passed a model of type `Firmas` in `return View(model);` statement in your details action.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the controller side, you are passing an object of type "Firmas" but your view is expecting the object "PcontacFirmasModel".

Update your action to send the PcontacFirmasModel object. you can use a mapper utility to map PcontacFirmasModel and Firmas.

Comment: I can't map it, Pcontac and Firmas are 2 different tables, merged into one using PcontacFirmasModel to get the 2 models in 1 view. If i try to map PcontacFirmasModel returns this: http://i.imgur.com/r9uQALP.png

Comment: in your view you set the main model as @model actiTest2.Models.PcontacFirmasModel, do the same in your action: `var model = new actiTest2.Model.PcontactFirmasModel { firmas = repo.GetFirmas(); } return View(model);`

Comment: For the key issue, just add the attribute `[Key]` at your primary key column, it is automatically set when you create an entity with the columns Id or TableNameId, by if you set the primary key as FirmasNo, you will need to add the key attribute.